# I want to be able to find a specific piece of data using the date

Tags: python, dictionary, search

This is a dictionary for some data. When I print it, it prints out in two distinct columns. I have looked on here for how to search through it and find a specific piece of data but It is not making any sense to me. If you could tell me how I might search through this (using the date) and then print out the data, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
rainfall = {
    '01/08/2014':1.0,
    '21/01/2015':0.20,
    '22/01/2015':0.10,
    '23/01/2015':1.00,
    '24/01/2015':0.30,
    '25/01/2015':0.40,
    '26/01/2015':0.75,
    '27/01/2015':0.20,
    '28/01/2015':1.00,
    '29/01/2015':0.20,
    '30/01/2015':0.20,
    '31/01/2015':0.30,
    }

for k, v in rainfall.items():
    print(f'{k:<4} - {v}')


def searching_for_data():
    whatdata=input("What date would you like to find (format: DD/MM/YYYY)")
    if whatdata in rainfall:
        print(find(whatdata))


finddata=input("Would you like to find a specific piece of data?")
if finddata == "Yes":
    searching_for_data()
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code (aside from the fact that it will never display the pair date value for obvious reasons)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your function to utilize `dict.__getitem__` or its syntactic sugar `[]`:

```
def searching_for_data():
    whatdata = input("What date would you like to find (format: DD/MM/YYYY)")
    if whatdata in rainfall:
        print(rainfall[whatdata])
```

But you should get in the habit of having functions `return` values. The above solution will also do nothing if the key does not exist, when you may wish to see `None`. For example, using `dict.get`:

```
def searching_for_data():
    """Return value if it exists in dictionary, else None"""
    whatdata = input("What date would you like to find (format: DD/MM/YYYY)")
    return rainfall.get(whatdata)

finddata = input("Would you like to find a specific piece of data?")
if finddata == "Yes":
    data = searching_for_data()
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
if whatdata in rainfall:
    print(find(whatdata)
```

to

```
if whatdata in rainfall.keys():
    print(rainfall[whatdata])
```

Comment: It says that 'key' is not defined. How do I get round this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the get-function in your `searching_for_data`:

```
def searching_for_data():
    whatdata = input("What date would you like to find (format: DD/MM/YYYY)")
    print(rainfall.get(whatdata, 'No data for ' + whatdata))
```

It allows you to define a default value (or a message for the user, in your case) if the key does not exist.

However, an even better way would be to let the function return the value and do the print command on the top level:

```
def searching_for_data():
    whatdata = input("What date would you like to find (format: DD/MM/YYYY)")
    return rainfall.get(whatdata, 'No data for ' + whatdata)

...

print(searching_for_data())
```